# Xamarin iOS: Unable to start new ViewController by tapping on remote notifications

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I am working on iOS, implemented FCM remote notifications. When i am tapping notification(when app open) it is not starting another screen. See below code i am using.

Here i am opening `ChildrenViewController` when app start by clicking on it

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {  

            Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;

                 var cvc = new ChildrenViewController();
                 cvc.childs = SISConst.Mychildren;
                 this.navCntl = new UINavigationController(cvc);
                 this.navCntl.NavigationBarHidden = true;
                 Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
                 SetRootViewController(this.navCntl, false);
         }

public void SetRootViewController(UIViewController rootViewController, bool animate)
        {
            if (animate)
            {
                var transitionType = UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight;
                if (Window == null)
                {
                    Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
                }
                Window.RootViewController = rootViewController;
                UIView.Transition(Window, 0.5, transitionType,
                                  () => Window.RootViewController = rootViewController,
                                  null);
            }
            else
            {
                Window.RootViewController = rootViewController;
            }
        }
```

On notifications click i am using separate nested class `CustomUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` which is not starting `ChildrenViewController` with updated data

```
     public class CustomUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        {
            public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
                    {
                        completionHandler();
                        var cvc = new ChildrenViewController();
                        cvc.studentId=studentId;
                        cvc.moduleName = moduleName;
                        cvc.isPush = true;
                        //var nv = new UINavigationController();
                        var appdelegate=UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;               
                        //appdelegate.Window.RootViewController = nv; 
                        var nv = appdelegate.Window.RootViewController as UINavigationController;                      
                        nv.PushViewController(cvc, false);         
                    }
        }
```

`ViewDidLoad()` of `ChildrenViewController` here i am checking whether app start by click or by tapping notification so that i am assigning different data

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    this.ShowStatusBarWithWhiteBg();
    this.DesignScreenTitleAs("");
    this.DesignLogoAppTitle();

    this.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;

    if (isPushNotification)
    {            
        ShowDashboardScreen();
    }
    else
    {             
        ShowChilds();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the delegate method DidReceiveNotificationResponse, take a look at the code,

```
var nv = new UINavigationController();
nv.PushViewController(cvc, false);
```

What you're doing here is, you're creating a new Navigation controller and trying to push children view controller to this newly created navigation controller stack. Problem here is, the navigation controller you created here is not set as root view controller of the window.

What you could do is, set this newly create navigation VC as your root view controller if that's what you want to do or get the reference of root view controller of the window which is a navigation controller as I see from your code and try to push the child view controller on it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Yogish See my updated code i am have assigned `RootView`. Still i am unable to push new `ViewController`.

Comment: app delegate is a singleton class, you shouldn't create a new instance of app delegate class as you're doing it in your new code. Also you shouldn't create a new window. What you can do is take already created app delegate by using UIApplication's shared() method and then access the window of app delegate and cast the root view controller to navigation controller and then push your child view controller.

Comment: @Yogish your answer worked for me. I have updated working code.

Comment: @PriyankaAgrawal One suggestion that I'd make is, don't change the rootviewcontroller in the DidReceiveNotificationResponse() again. Because, you've already set a navigation controller as root view controller in FinishedLaunching() access the same root view controller and push your child vc.

Comment: @Yogish Your suggestion was good, it solved navigation issues. I have tried the same look at updated code am i doing right?

Comment: Yep you are using the navigation controller (Root Viewcontroller of the window). So that's good.